# Array merging for combining key values in another array with no repetition of same objects using javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried merging arrays

```
var x =[{n:'s1', a:'sang', m1: 10}, {n:'s2', a:'sang', m1: 20}]

var y =[{n:'s1', a:'sang', m2: 20}, {n:'s2', a:'sang', m2: 20}]

after merging var a and var b I need result in var c like,

c = [{n:'s1', a:'sang', m1: 10, m2: 20},{{n:'s2', a:'sang', m1: 20,m2: 20}]
```

Comment: do you mean "without repetition of the same property"? because all the 4 objects in your example are actually different (and not only because of their reference, for once)..

Comment: yes without repeating same property

Comment: Actually, I have to bind a multiple JSON in a single grid having one data of multiple years but one of the objects is going to have property come in common as "Company Name".
But next data should merge just in the same row with preloaded previous data without fetching the same company name so as not to rebind with the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object(assign)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Object/assign) method:

```js
var x =[{n:'s1', a:'sang', m1: 10}, {n:'s2', a:'sang', m1: 20}]

var y =[{n:'s1', a:'sang', m2: 20}, {n:'s2', a:'sang', m2: 20}]

var c = [];

x.forEach(a => {
 c.push( Object.assign({}, a, y.find( b => b.n === a.n) ) );
});

console.log( c );
```